# Ruby: could not load oracle driver

Tags: ruby, oracle, dbi

I'm a ruby beginner and having the following error.

```
Driver: dbi:Oracle:
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/dbi/dbi.rb:511:in `load_driver': Could not load driver (no such file to load -- oracle) (DBI::InterfaceError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/dbi/dbi.rb:429:in `data_sources'
    from /tmp/list-ruby-dbsupport.rb:4
    from /tmp/list-ruby-dbsupport.rb:2:in `each'
    from /tmp/list-ruby-dbsupport.rb:2
```

This is my script (list-ruby-dbsupport.rb):

```
require 'dbi'
DBI.available_drivers.each do |driver| 
    puts "Driver: " + driver 
    DBI.data_sources(driver).each do |dsn|  
        puts "  Datasource: " + dsn 
    end
end
```

I'm using Mac and I just installed dbi with the following command (No error were thrown during installation)

```
ruby setup.rb config –-with=dbi,dbd_oracle,dbd_mysql
```

I installed dbd-mysql-0.4.4 and dbd-odbc-0.2.5 too - hoping that might fix the error but it didnt.
Could anyone tell me how to fix or where to check please?

Comment: Are you familiar with Perl? DBI isn't commonly used in Ruby, unlike Perl where it is THE db access module.

Comment: Not really. I came from Java background. I was reading 'Ruby Developer Guide from syngress' and following some instruction on how to access DB with ruby. I think I'll need oracle client before installing 'dbd_oracle'? How do I remove it back?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the [ruby-oci8](http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/) library?

Comment: No, I don't have sqlplus/oracle running on my Mac. Can't find oracle-xe package for Mac. :(